# Algebraic element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$K \leq L, a \in L$

I am looking at the proof that if $a$ is algebraic over $K$, then $K(a)=K[a]$ :

We show that $K[a]$ is a field, then we have that $K \subseteq  K[a] \subseteq  K(a) \subseteq L$.

Let $0 \neq c \in K[a]$, then $c=f(a), f \in K[x]$.

Let $p(x)=Irr(a,K)$.

Since $p(a)=0$ and $f(a) \neq 0$, we have that $p(x) \nmid f(x)$, so we have that $(p(x), f(x))=1$.

Therefore, there are $h(x), g(x) \in K[x]$ with $h(x) \cdot p(x)+g(x) \cdot f(x)=1$.

For $x=a$: $h(a) \cdot p(a)+g(a) \cdot f(a)=1 \Rightarrow h(a) \cdot 0+g(a) \cdot f(a)=1 \Rightarrow g(a) \cdot f(a)=1$.

$$$$

We have the following:
$K \leq L, a \in L$

$$K[a]=\{f(a), \text{ with } f(x) \in K[x]\}$$
$$K(a)=\{f(a) \cdot g^{-1}(a), \ \ f(x), g(x) \in K[x], g(a) \neq 0 \}$$

Why does it stand that $$K \subseteq K[a] \subseteq K(a) \subseteq L$$ ??

Could you explain me the proof above?? How did we show that $K(a)=K[a]$??

Does the reverse also stand?? Does it stand that if $K(a)=K[a]$, then $a$ is algebraic over $K$??

Comment: It should be obvious that $K[a] \subseteq K(a)$, can you recall their definitions?

Comment: Is it $K[a] \subseteq K(a)$, because $f(a) \in K[a]$ can be written as $f(a) \cdot 1^{-1} \in K(a)$ ??

Comment: Recall that $K(a)$ is the smallest field that contains $K$ and $a$. So if $K[a]$ is a field, then $K(a)\subset K[a]$. The other inclusion is given by the fact that you said. So $K(a)=K[a]$.

Comment: What they are proving is that every element in $K[a]$ has a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: I understand!!! And how could we prove that if $K(a)=K[a]$, then $a$ is algebraic over $K$??

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, the answer is yes. $K(a) = K[a]$ iff $a$ is algebraic.
If $a$ is not algebraic, then it is transcendental, so $K[a]\cong K[X]$, which is not a field. To see this last result, use the evaluation homomorphism at $a$, $f:K[X]\to L$. We have that $K[a]=f(K[X])$ and if $a$ is transcendental, then there is no polynomial $g\in K[X]$ such that $g(a)=0$, so $\ker f= 0$ and $f$ is an isomophism.

Comment: I got stuck right now... Could you explain me further this proof??

Comment: What are the parts of the proof you don't understand?